# How to pass a CollectionViewSource to a converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

I have something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="filteredSymbols" Source="{Binding Symbols ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                              Filter="Symbols_CollectionViewSource_Filter" IsLiveFilteringRequested="True" >
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
                <sys:String>DisplayPage</sys:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<Border Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource filteredSymbols}, Converter={StaticResource MultiThresholdToReturnValueConverter}}" >
```

I am trying to pass the `ListCollectionView` to the converter in the border background property, but it will keep passing null.

I have also tried adding `Path=.` to the border background binding which made no difference.

Am I missing something?

---

**Edit:**

I've just tried an identical binding on a `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` and it will pass the `ListCollectionView` object to the converter fine, using this code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource filteredSymbols}, , Converter={StaticResource MultiThresholdToReturnValueConverter}}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="item" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Whats going on?

Comment: Passing something into converter means using [ConverterParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter). I don't see anything like this. Can you clarify what you want to pass? Where is `ListCollectionView` you mentioned? Where did you try `Path=` or what exactly doesn't works? Where you get `null`?

Comment: @Sinatr By pass i mean call the converter with the static resource as the `value` argument on the convert method of the converter. And by `ListCollectionView` I meant the static resource `filteredSymbols`'s `View` property (which is the filtered list). Also I added `Path=.` the the border background binding.

Comment: So didn't you try `Path=View`?

Comment: @Clemens yes I tried it and I got the error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'View' property not found on 'object' ''ListCollectionView'`, So i guessed it would auto pass the `View` property?

Comment: I just did a very quick test with a simple static resource and a converter;  the resource was passed to the converter as expected.  Unless something more complex is happening with a `CollectionViewSource`, or in your specific converter, I'm not sure why you would be having a problem.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Did you try it was a `CollectionViewSource` as it seems to be something to do with `CollectionViewSource` (if you read my edit)

Comment: I'm trying to rig up a more complex test, closer to you specific example now.

Comment: When I don't set a `Path` on the binding with a `Source` set to a `CollectionViewSource`, I see a binding error in the output window. "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '' property not found on 'object' ''ListCollectionView'...".  I don't see how your code would work without a `Path`.

Comment: I do find it odd that I'm not seeing the same thing as you though. Rather than pass `null`, it isn't even _calling_ my converter.

Comment: @BradleyUffner That is weird. Have you tried using `Path=.` with it? Thanks very much btw, really appreciate it

Comment: Yes, `Path` results in the same binding error.  Are you using Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: Hmm... When I bind the `CollectionViewSource` to a `ListBox.ItemsSource`, the binding works fine.  The odd behavior only seems to happen when the property being bound isn't a collection.

Comment: @BradleyUffner no im using 4.6.1, also I just tried passing it as the converter paramater and it passed a `CollectionViewSource` object with the `View` property is null. Also yeah its very wierd - I can't seem to find this behaviour documented anywhere

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround to this problem by setting the resource to a `DependencyProperty` in the code behind and binding to that instead like so:

Code behind:

```
...

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilteredSymbolsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FilteredSymbols), typeof(CollectionViewSource), typeof(SymbolSummaryControl));
public CollectionViewSource FilteredSymbols
{
    set { SetValue(FilteredSymbolsProperty, value); }
    get { return (CollectionViewSource)GetValue(FilteredSymbolsProperty); }
 }

public ctor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FilteredSymbols = (CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["filteredSymbols"];
    Debug.Assert(FilteredSymbols != null);
}

...
```

And then using the binding:

```
Background="{Binding Path=FilteredSymbols.View, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource MultiThresholdToReturnValueConverter}}"
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using the `ConvertParameter` property?

Comment: @mm8 the `View` property was still null when I used the `ConvertParameter ` method also I plan to use the `ConvertParameter` in the converter

Comment: That's fair enough :)